# Inserts to elasticsearch datastreams using springboot is throwing error "only write ops with an op_type of create are allowed in data streams"

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

We are using

```
    @Repository
public interface ElasticSearchExampleRepository
    extends ElasticsearchRepository<ExampleEntity, String> {}
```

When we try to do bulk inserts using repository.saveAll to write to datastreams, we get the below error.

```
 org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.BulkFailureException: Bulk operation has failures. Use ElasticsearchException.getFailedDocuments() for detailed messages [{e4c5f33e-4e96-4e1b-840e-fba413ab5ad1=ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=only write ops with an op_type of create are allowed in data streams
```

Is there a way to change the `op_type to create` in our spring boot java application?

Answer (score 1):

When `saveAll` creates the data for the underlying bulk operation it converts the single entities to `IndexQuery` instances (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/AbstractElasticsearchTemplate.java#L222-L243).

An `IndexQuery` object can have the `OpType` set, the default being `null`, resulting in the default behaviour.

You would need to use the `ElasticsearchOperations.bulkIndex(java.util.List<org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.IndexQuery>, org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.mapping.IndexCoordinates)` method directly instead of using the repository `saveAll` method and when building the `IndexQuery` objects set the `OpType`to `create`.

Not the most comfortable way, but currently the only one in Spring Data Elasticsearch.